# How to fix and avoid micro USB connection issues?

Tags: pcb-design, usb-device

Some of my smartphones / tablets developed after some years problems with their micro USB connectivity.

E. g.:

1. Motorola Moto E 2nd Generation
2. Nexus 7 2013
3. Samsung S3

A connection could only be achieved when bending the cable / connector in a certain angle.

For the Motorola, in the beginning only file transfer problems occurred, later on also for charging. For the Samsung S3 and Nexus both charging and file transfer got difficult / impossible.

This happens for all sort of cables. These cables also work well with my other equipment.

Corrosion does not seem to be the issue: careful scratching away any rust of the socket pins did not help.

I wonder whether the circuit board developed some kind of micro fractions near the USB socket, but I am not sure.

My questions are:

**1. How can I fix this problem? (perhaps by creating a 'soldering bypass' on the circuit board?)**

**2. When I buy new smartphones / tables: how can I avoid this kind of deterioration from the beginning? Are there any models / manufacturers that e. g. don't have the micro USB connectivity directly on the circuit board but designed it somehow replaceable? Or do some of the manufacturers use a different / thicker material for their circuit boards?**

**3. Is USB-C here any better than micro-USB?**

My idea of using a permanent pass-through dongle is probably counter productive, as this would lead to a more frequent strain on the circuit board / socket (when having it in the pocket etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only have hands-on experience with the Nexus 7 2012 and 2013. In both of these devices the USB connector can become as you describe: charging is intermittent and might only work with some cables and when held at a certain angle.

I found the issue is caused by the solder connections of the USB connector getting loose. Re-soldering (re-heating with some flux and very little solder) the connector pins can solve this issue. That might be a temporary solution though as the design is such that stress can occur on the solder joint.

If you have no experience with soldering such small connectors then **practice** on some PCB that you no longer need. Of course you will need a soldering iron with a very small tip. Consider that you could ask a local phone repair shop to do this re-soldering for you, it only takes a few minutes of work.

USB-C is indeed a more robust connector **however** note that in what I mention above, it is not so much the connector itself that causes the issue. What causes the issue is **stress** between the PCB on which the connector is mounted and the connector itself.

So a different design for the connector and/or PCB might solve that. There are many devices that do not have the issue despite having a micro-USB port.

Consider buying a device with **wireless charging** so that there is no need to always use the USB connector to charge the device.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer: "1. How can I fix this problem?" and "soldering".

OP asked Oct 29, 2020, so regarding the Samsung Galaxy S III / 3 (SGS3), this is approaching a vintage electronics repair question.* However, the micro USB-B failure issues apply across brands and devices up to the broad implementation of USB-C ports.

I found a YouTube teaching video specific to SGS3 micro USB-B port soldering replacement:

Microsoldering 101: Galaxy S3 USB Charge Port Replacement [1h8m]
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jGZKsuaJlpo

The most important part of this video is from observing several big tools, that microsoldering requires a thousand dollars more or less, of stuff to buy.

Looking at my SGS3 using a hand microscope (unlike in the teaching video), my SGS3 port's solder points were not broken. I observed that the SGS3's metal port shell is just too flimsy, causing it to easily bend open wider with repeated use. It needs some kind of reinforcing metal band around the outside of the shell to keep it tight. (I haven't solved that how-to problem, but it appears doable. Say, with a copper wire wrap that's solder tacked? That should require only classic soldering.)

After I saw their SGS3 mainboard removed, I realized that I had enough bench experience to just-right-squeeze the exterior lips of my own SGS3's USB shell, using the near-hinge (rear interior) of my chain nose pliers. I did so to one of my SGS3s; there was some prompt improvement in my SGS3's USB port looseness with fewer charging fails.

Next, I noticed that third-party USB-A to micro USB-B metal-shell plugs are made slightly too small and loose compared to brand name OEM plugs. I've read that a world-famous major retailer bargains with Chinese manufacturers over an extra penny per unit for sale at retail price - so I don't think these undersized metal plugs are an accident.

Also, most of third-party micro USB-B plugs are made without two extra leaf springs opposite the latch side, that some OEM plugs do have. Again, these plugs should be reinforcing-metal banded around the outside of the shell - but I don't know a way to do that with precision and chrome conductivity while retaining the dual latch function. I'll just have to pay more for OEMs that aren't fake. (Some vendor photos of the micro USB-B plug end have non-OEM clues that are hidden, such as any extra leaf springs.)

*It's increasingly difficult to find working SGS3 browsers with matching website certificates, but I persist using them for news reading and internet radio. Their replaceable-battery electronics refuse to wear out, as have both SGS4 (charging?) and SGS5 (cellular radio overheating) phones owned by a friend. Wi-Fi phones use a small fraction of the electricity (and junction-diffusion-wear repair cost) of a desktop computer.

SGS3 buttons do wear out, but those can be worked around with instant glue button fabrication and/or unbent large paper clips. "Launched in 2012, [SGS3] had sold more than 80 million units overall, making it the most sold phone in the S series." (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S_III)  Thus, for us bitter-enders, replaceable parts are still available from eBay.

Comment: It would be VERY useful if you post some photos. It is difficult to understand what you are talking about. "reinforcing metal band around the outside of the shell to keep it tight" Who will understand what metal band and what shell you are talking about?

Comment: > " Who will understand what metal band and what shell you are talking about?"

Comment: Did you watch the video? Without it, I agree that you might not understand what SGS3 micro USB-B connector shell needs repair. * If you don't have enough bench repair experience (which the OP and 2020 answer seem to have), you might not be able to recognize a 'shell', risk the quick shell-squeeze repair that I did, or be able to perform copper-wrap-solder banding. * I didn't repair-band my shell, so no photo is available. 'Banding' is a classic bench repair technique for broken round objects. (Banding with plastic: "Demonstration of Ty-Wrap Gun"  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DA8c9TP0ax8)